# Two UITableViews in one file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Is it possible to have two UITableViews using the same controller file? If so how do you differentiate the two? If not then how would you control them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes definately.  Create two instance variables one for each tableview.

The table view delegate methods include a pointer to the table view calling them in the method do something like,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(tableView != [self tableView1]){
      //do stuff
    }
    //handle tableView2
    else{

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

The differentiation is possible due to the method signatures of the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource interfaces.  If you look at either interface you'll notice that they both pass a reference to the UITableView instance for which the method was invoked...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Check out the [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) and [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) API docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the other posters shows, it is possible.
But there is another approach, where each TableView has it own controller. These controller get instantiated in another UIViewController. This is less coupled, so re-use ability is greater. For communication between the two UIViewController use delegation.
[Have a look on my sample code.](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/TwoTableViews)

Answer (score 0):

Use the different tags for Your UITableViews.