# How to work in two UITableView in a single View Controller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How to work in two UITableView in a single View Controller in ios.In my app i designed the textfield and the buttons in a tableview(FirstTableVie).And i try to implement the comboBox in one of the textfield.Here the i implement the delegate function for comboBox tableview(SecondTableView), while i run this it shows the SecondTableView the FirstTableView  is not displaying.So hlep me to implement the two bale view in a single ViewController.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView==self.FirstTableView)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(tableView==self.SecondTableView){
        return [stateArray count];
    }
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if(tableView==self.FirstTableView)
    {
    }
    else if(tableView==self.SecondTableView)
    {
        static NSString *identifier=@"Cell";
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if(cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please provide the source code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two UITableViews in one file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477359/two-uitableviews-in-one-file)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just create custom class/objects that you set the delegate methods to let them own it and implment the delegate methods in your custom classes.

i.e.

```
@interface TableViewHandler : NSObject
@end
@implmentation
// implement delegate methods
@end
```

then initialize and allocate these objects and assign them to the delegates of your two table views.

so in your view controller you can do

```
tableViewHandler *one = [[TableViewHandler alloc] init]; // you can implment an init if you want otherwise it goes to the NSObject init
```

and then assign the delegate methods of your first table view to this object.

so instead of the typical in a viewController

```
myTableview.delegate = self
```

you would do

```
myTableView.delegate = self.one;
```

and of course dataSource as well.

The advantage of this over if this table view or that is you can segregate the code.

It depends if you want re-usability of code. There is less re-usability in ViewControllers that are structured with if this class or that or that. Custom classes can be cleanly modified and carried around to other projects as needed. For example if you want to use one of these tables in another project you'd be messing around with copying and paste from the all the delegate methods you add the if else logic to.  If you isolate the code you can just port the file.

Comment: This is the best option probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can check like below.I wrote only the conditions not entire code..

```
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(tableView==self.FirstTableView)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(tableView==self.SecondTableView){
        return [stateArray count];
    }
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     UITableViewCell *cell;
     static NSString *identifier=@"Cell";
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
      cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    if(tableView==self.FirstTableView)
    {
    }
    else if(tableView==self.SecondTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: it gives error,i already try this i fixed like UITableViewCell *cell;
    if(tableView==self.totaltableView)
    {
    }
    else if(tableView==self.combotableView)
    {
        static NSString *identifier=@"Cell";
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if(cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=[stateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;

Comment: your's give the control may reach and of non-void function

Comment: Check my updated answer..I modified your code to fix error.You need to initialise cell in both cases..!

Answer (score 0):

Add tags to two tableview and check the if the condition while handling in the
table view delegate like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section ;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(tableView.tag==1) {
   } else {
    }

}
```

I just posted the logic how to approach

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't see a problem here. Every delegate and dataSource protocol method returns a refernce to a prticular TableView. Just set you view controller as a delegate to both tables and find out which of two is used in callback. You can distinguish tables by tag.

Example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        return 5;
    }else if (tableView.tag == 2){
        return 10;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (tableView.tag == 1) {
        cell = [self configreCellForFirstTableAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }else if (tableView.tag == 2){
       cell = [self configreCellForSecondTableAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    return cell;
}
```